# How to determine which button is getting clicked in ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a collection of `Person` that I display within an `ItemsControl` with each row consisting of a `TextBlock` and a `Button`. When I click on a button, I want to do something with the corresponding `Person`.

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text={Binding Name}>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="X" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**C#**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with the Person corresponding with the button clicked
}
```

In `Button_Click`, how do I determine which `Button` I actually clicked? (And consequently, to which `Person` it corresponds to?)

Comment: Normally you should have a command which operates in same data context as textblock, i.e. have access to `Person` properties. MVVM approach: make VM for `Person`, add command there, bind button to command.

Comment: The parameter named `sender` is the actual *sender* of the event.

Comment: This is usually the wrong way to go about it. WPF/UWP and XAML were designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about 90% of WPF's power and runs into issues at every other corner. Moreover not a lot of people stick around without MVVM. If you are registering ButtonClick Events, this is definitely not MVVM. I wrote a short intro a few years back, it should still be valid: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm

Comment: @Orace Unpacking the sender is a good example for those other approaches. Generally you do not create buttons. You create a view model with a command and have elements like Buttons, Shortcuts, MenuItems, etc, represent them to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**C#**

I think you mean that:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    PersonClass person = button.DataContext as PersonClass;
    person.example = "example";
    // ...
}
```

Thats how you get the object of the button you have clicked on.